# Why can't InDesign create this small label?

Tags: adobe-indesign, document-setup, size

I am trying to design a small return address label following the printer's guidelines:

[image]

However, **InDesign** isn't letting me create a label this size:

[image]

[image]

I really just want to set a size and start designing. The error messages make no logical sense because there are no "columns" and all margins and bleeds are set to 0.

What's blocking me?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. ‍♂️ Edit: Ahh! Are you trying to *change* the size of an *existing* document? That might give you trouble if you have different dimensions and/or margins on some pages. You can't change them all using *Document Setup*.

Comment: @Wolff ah ok can I make the changes to an existing document?

Answer (score 3):

Once you have manually changed the *Page Size* or *Margins* of individual pages, you can no longer change all pages using *Document Setup*.

You could just make the changes you want *without* using *Document Setup*.

The **Page Size** can be set to the wanted dimensions by selecting all pages in the *Pages* panel and then clicking the *Edit page size* button in the bottom of the *Pages* panel.

The **Margins** can be set to *0* (or whatever fitting value you want) by selecting all pages in the *Pages* panel and using *Layout > Margins and Columns*.

If you want to re-enable *Document Setup* to change your document, you must first give all pages the same *Page Size* and *Margins* (and *Bleed* and *Slug*). Then enter *Document Setup*, type in those same values and click *OK*. Now if you enter *Document Setup* again, it has regained control of the settings.

Comment: Thanks. There’s only one page in this document which is why I was confused I couldn’t change its size

Comment: I see. But does it make sense now? Had you set margins on that page different from those in document setup?

Comment: So what you are saying is that one cannot change margin settings in the document setup page? And they will not adjust automatically. I think I understand

Comment: I'm saying that if you change the margins or page size so they no longer correspond to the settings in *Document Setup*, you can no longer control those settings in *Document Setup*. Not until you manually make sure the settings are the same on *all* pages and in *Document Setup*. Then *Document Setup* regains control.